# Elastic Beanstalk and Enhanced Networking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Has anyone been able to get AWS enhanced networking to work in Elastic Beanstalk? There is no documentation on how to do it that I can find, and it would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems if you build inside a VPC, it's there by default.

Comment: I might have that backward. If it's part of the AMI you use, then it's installed, but it MUST be inside a VPC for it to work.